# Sprite Kit SKTexture animation height unexpectedly changing

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, sktexture, sktextureatlas

I am using a `SKTextureAtlas` to animate a `SKSpriteNode`. The animation works, but it looks weird because for some reason the sprite's height is changing several times in the animation. This also causes the y position to change as well. Everything else remains the same except for the height and the y. The only thing I can think of is there are different amounts of transparent pixels within each frame. Each image is the same size though. Even when I use `SKAction.animateWithTextures(atlasFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: true, restore: false)`, with resize set to true and false, the problem persists.

Comment: You didn't change the anchor point for the Sprite did you? Default is .5, .5 (center of the sprite) you shouldn't see the position change at all. A video of the animation would be helpful when trying to identify the problem. Maybe upload the video to dropbox and share the link?

Comment: try passing false for the resize parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard about this issue with textures.
I recommend you to make all textures of same size and add background for all images of 1% alpha (it wont be visible but it will be where). This is happening because invisible background is cut.

You can watch this guide for more information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDwSR3e6nN0

Comment: I was able to add a background to all of them that matched the background of the scene. It seems to be working now, thanks.